# Simba ODBC connection to delta table & read data from delta format tables using .Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, delta-lake, simba

I am trying to read data from delta format tables using c# via simba odbc driver.
delta format table sample : https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#-create-a-table&language-python

Have downloaded and configured simba odbc as instructed in
https://www.simba.com/products/Spark/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/mac/content/odbc/configuring/drivermanager.htm

I am able to successfully connect to the spark thrift server after this configuration. However, I am unable to read data from the delta format tables.

```
using(dbConnection)
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");
                OdbcCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
                dbCommand.CommandText =  "SELECT * FROM accnt LIMIT 10"; 
                OdbcDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if(dbReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while(dbReader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", 
dbReader.GetString(0),dbReader.GetString(1), dbReader.GetString(2));
dbReader.GetString(1));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No Rows Found.");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Close  !");
            }
```

Error Messages is :

```
Unhandled exception. System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000] [Simba][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '0' error message: 'Error running query: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DELTA.DefaultSource'.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at cdp_deltalake_poc.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add configuration options and Delta Lake package when you're starting the Thrift Server.  This is done the same way as submitting applications to Spark. For example:

```sh
sbin/start-thriftserver.sh \
  --conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension \
  --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog \
  --packages 'io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0'
```

You need to adjust version of the Delta Lake package depending on the Spark version (I did use 0.8.0 with Spark 3.0.1).

After that I can query the data that I've created.