# How to Connect to Databricks table from c# code using JBDC/ODBC?

Tags: c#, .net, databricks, delta-lake, jdbc-odbc

I have created a c# windows service and want to Connect to Databricks Delta table from c# code using JDBC/ODBC connection with below host for updating/inserting in couple of databricks delta tables.

Trying using SIMBA ODBC connection but got the error as Data source name not found and no default driver specified'

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        // Build connection string
        OdbcConnectionStringBuilder odbcConnectionStringBuilder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Driver = "Simba Spark ODBC Driver", //Simba Spark ODBC Driver
           Dsn = "Simba Spark"
        };
        odbcConnectionStringBuilder.Add("Host", "sas-tes-dev.cloud.databricks.com");
        odbcConnectionStringBuilder.Add("Port", "443");
        odbcConnectionStringBuilder.Add("SSL", "1");
        odbcConnectionStringBuilder.Add("ThriftTransport", "2");
        odbcConnectionStringBuilder.Add("AuthMech", "3");
        odbcConnectionStringBuilder.Add("UID", "token");
        odbcConnectionStringBuilder.Add("PWD", "dapisds62728299255b4");
        odbcConnectionStringBuilder.Add("HTTPPath", "sql/protocolv1/o/6709534942857832/0208-221830-graph177");


        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(odbcConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlQuery = "select * from mpre_sm.innsme";
            OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
            connection.Open();
            OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(reader.GetName(i) + "\t");
            }

            Console.Write("\n");

            reader.Close();
            command.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Please help to provide C# code snipped and suggestions to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/340847/can-a-net-c-application-connect-and-query-from-an.html

Comment: I am using apache databricks , I haven't tried any c# connectivity yet and want to stablish the connection to read /write the data, not sure from where to start writing a code for creating connection with above configuration I have shared.

Comment: Why don't you try this example and confirm that you can at least connect. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750474/simba-odbc-connection-to-delta-table-read-data-from-delta-format-tables-using

Comment: Post the code that you already tried

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I just tried using simba odbc connection , getting this error :- 
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'

Comment: @AlexOtt please check the code snippet I have updated in original question , i have installed SIMBA oledb driver and connecting with that

Comment: Dsn that you are trying to use has to be configured in ODBC drivers system utility, 64 bit if the machine is 64 bit and 32 bit otherwise on a windows machine.